# If jquery slideToggle element is toggled then hide all other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very inexperienced with jquery/javascript and am trying to limp my way through this one. I have found other posts that advise on how to accomplish something similar to what I am trying to do but my knowledge on javascript syntax is so limited. If anyone could help I would appreciate it a ton.

What I am trying to do is pretty simple. If there is a `<div>` that is open, hide all others. Below is what I have accomplished so far.

**index**

```
<section class="about" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div id="hidden1"><h3>+ Heading 3</h3></div>
        <div class="showtext1">
          <p>Example text one</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hidden2"><h3>+ Heading 2</h3></div>
        <div class="showtext2">
          <p>Example text two</p>
        </div>

        <div id="hidden3"><h3>+ Heading 3</h3></div>
          <div class="showtext3">
            <p>Example text three</p>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**javascript**

```
$(function() {
    $('.showtext1')
        .hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hidden1').click(function() {
        $('.showtext1').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
// .showtext2
$(function() {
    $('.showtext2')
        .hide();
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hidden2').click(function() {
        $('.showtext2').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
// .showtext3
// $(function() {
//     $('.showtext3')
//         .hide();
// });
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hidden3').click(function() {
        $('.showtext3').slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make your code dynamic so that you don't need to worry about adding more jQuery code if your list grew from 3 items to 4 or many. Also, if there's plus (+) sign to indicate that there's more content, then the plus should turn into minus(-) to indicate that you can collapse the displayed content now for better user experience.  [**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/vwf4ykg4/2/)

HTML

```
<div class="accordion">
  <dl>
    <dt><h3><span>+</span> Heading 3</h3></dt>
    <dd><p>Example text one</p></dd>
    <dt><h3><span>+</span> Heading 2</h3></dt>
    <dd><p>Example text two</p></dd>
  </dl>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('.accordion dd').filter(':nth-child(n+4)').hide();
    $('.accordion dl').on('click', 'dt', function() {
       $('.accordion dd').hide();
       $(this).siblings("dt").find("span").text("+");
       $(this).find("span").text("-");
       $(this).next().slideDown();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use so many `div` elements uselessly since bootstrap requires you to add several divs for layout.

Code Explanation:

1. When the document loading is completed lets slideUp all `p` elements.
2. When a `h3` is clicked, let's find the `p` element next to it and slide it down. Using slide toggle helps to hide the `p` element when that same `h3` is clicked again.
3. The functioning of second line in the click function will be clear with the following scenario. So firstly if you click on a `h3` the `p` element sides down. But when you click on another `h3` after that. The `not` function targets all the `p` elements other than the currently clicked `p` element and slides all of them up. So rememeber the `p` element of the firstly clicked `h3` is still showing up so we need to hide that when you click on another `h3` in your second click.

Hope that explanation helps understanding the code.

**Modiefied HTML (removing un necessary divs)**

```
<section class="about" id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h3>+ Heading 1</h3>
        <p>Example text one</p>
        <h3>+ Heading 2</h3>
        <p>Example text two</p>
        <h3>+ Heading 3</h3>
        <p>Example text three</p>
       </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

**Modiefied JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").slideUp();
  $("h3").click(function(){
    $(this).next("p").slideToggle("slow");
    $("p").not($(this).next("p")).slideUp();
  });
});
```

Check out this codepen with the solution.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGzgBd

Comment: You are a beautiful person!

Comment: Your JS in the codepen works properly however using what you posted does'nt. If you correct it, then I'll mark it as answered. Thank you again!

Comment: Ok. I was checking to fix the bug. Updated the code. Thanks.